# Return conditional statements to new line when organizing code(Python)?

Tags: python, if-statement, organization

So I know when listing variables in object class, you can return every line to list the variables vertically for better organization:

```
class Thing(object):
  def __init__(x,
               y,
               z):
```

Is it possible to do the same thing with conditionals in an `if` statement, like so?

```
if condition1 and
   condition2 and
   condition3:
```

Obviously that's probably not the right syntax for it since it doesn't work, but it's a good example of what I'm trying to do in order to organize my code so I don't have scroll to right when something has long names for conditional satements.

Comment: you can split lines using '\' in python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parentheses to the rescue!

```
if (1 == 1 and
    2 == 2 and
    3 == 3):
   # ...
```